# What do plot options `ljoin` and `lmitre` do?

Tags: r

In R's help to `?par` the two options `ljoin` and `lmitre` are documented. When setting them to different values, I do not see a difference. I do not understand their description either. Could someone please provide an illustrative example what these options do and when they are useful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From one of the older readmes:

*’lend’, ’ljoin’, and ’lmitre’ control the cap style and join style for drawing lines (only noticeable on thick lines or borders). Currently, only PostScript, PDF, X11, and Quartz respond to these settings.*

So let's try

```
pdf("mitre.pdf")
par(ljoin=0)
y=c(0,1,0,5,0)
plot(y,lwd=20,type="l",ylim=c(0,10))
par(ljoin=1)
lines(y+2,lwd=20,type="l")
par(ljoin=2)
lines(y+4,lwd=20,type="l")
dev.off()
```

[image]

And here the real mitre (never have used it)

```
pdf("realymitre.pdf")
par(ljoin=1) # lmitre only active for ljoin=1
y=c(0,30,0)
x=c(-1:1)
plot(x, y,lwd=10,type="l",ylim=c(0,40),xlim=c(-20,20))
par(ljoin=1, lmitre=30) # default lmitre=10
lines(x+4,y,lwd=10,type="l",ylim=c(0,40))
dev.off()
```

[image]